# admin generator doesn't generate a class

Tags: php, plugins, symfony1, admin, generator

Hi
I'm using symfony 1.2.7 with Doctrine.
Tryng to port a plugin originally written with Propel, but running into problems.
In one of the plugins modules the generator.yml starts like:

```
generator:
  class:          sfDoctrineGenerator
  param:
    model_class:  Page
    theme:        admin
```

I always get "Fatal error: Class 'cmsPageGeneratorConfiguration' not found in .../cache/backend/dev/modules/autoCmsPage/actions/actions.class.php on line 18" I googled on it, but unlike my case anybody else seems like to missing the Base*GeneratorConfiguration class which is in it's place for me.
If i write something else to the theme directive the error goes away but the config is ignored, and the default forms and lists are shown, can't set even a title...
Why isn't the missing class auto-generated as it's supposed? I'm really stuck here, thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this SF version, but did you try to clear the cache?

```
php symfony cc
```

This worked for me with similar error messages.